# Are two-wheeler battery types interchangable

Tags: honda, battery

I have a Honda Activa 2007 model. The battery fitted in it is electrolyte topup battery which requires distilled water to be filled up from time to time. My question is can a maintenance free battery be fitted in place of an electrolyte battery?

Comment: Maintenance-free batteries are also electrolyte batteries, they just don't have a way to fill up electrolyte (unless you REALLY want to do it), so if it dries up you replace it. Other than that there is no difference which one you use.

Comment: @IanRingrose  I don't see this as a duplicate.  There are two answers.  The first doesn't answer his question and the second (mine) definitely doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @sam  Yes, you can replace battery types, just ensure it has the same output and ratings as the OEM.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've made this swap myself on one of my bikes. You just need to make sure that the maximum current (sometimes referred to as 'cold cranking amperage') and Ah ratings are at least as much as the old battery. It doesn't matter if the new battery has higher Ah or current ratings, that won't cause any harm.